# In Google Data Studio, how can I join 2 tables to be available in a report?

Tags: google-data-studio

When I'm building a report in [Google Data Studio](https://www.google.com/analytics/data-studio/) from a MySQL source, I appear to only ever be able to work with 1 table per data source:

[image]

If I attempt to edit or change the datasource, I'm simply shown the single table that was selected when I created the datasource:

[image]

I need to join this table with another table. In this particular instance, I want to join with `customer` on `customer_id` to pull in customer data so that I can attach the customer's address to the [Geo Map object](https://support.google.com/360suite/datastudio/answer/6293184?hl=en#add_a_geo_map) on my report. You can see that object in the first screenshot.

Is there a way to join 2 tables and work with their data when building reports? The help docs aren't clear to me in this regard, and it appears to me that when you build a data source from an external database, you're forced to drill down all the way to the table level. Do I need to create 2 datasources to pull info from 2 different tables in the same database? If so, can they be joined so that data from both is available in the same report?

Comment: Then your question is unclear. Some screen shots might be useful.

Comment: I've added screenshots to be more clear. Thanks for adding the tag. It is a relatively new product, I think more people will be asking questions about how to use it as time goes on. I've reached out to someone at Google for help as well – if I get this working I'll post back with an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [the docs](https://support.google.com/360suite/datastudio/answer/7088031#how_to_connect_to_mysql) as of this posting:

> A Data Studio data source can connect to a single MySQL database table.

You *can* use multiple data sources (read: tables) in the same report, but you can't join them to use multiple data sources in one object, such as a bar graph or geo map. I was told by someone on the Data Studio team that joins are on their roadmap.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually add a joined tables to Google Data Studio - but it requires an extra step. In your mysql database, you must first create a view of the joined tables.

Here is a link that explains how to do that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12352048/mysql-create-view-joining-two-tables

When you connect to your mysql datasource the joined view will show up in the list as a table in your selected database.

Comment: Great idea! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Could you please clarify how to make the views show up in Google Data Studio? I created a view in my MySQL database, but it does not appear when I create a new datasource with this MySQL connection, I only see my tables. Thanks.

Comment: @MartijndeMilliano Did you solve the issue? I was wondering about the same thing.

Comment: If someone comes back here, what I had to do was to create a brand new data source and then the view appeared.

Answer (score 0):

The Data Studio MySQL connector accepts a SQL query, so you can JOIN the tables freely.